# Dynamic number of inserts with Ecto.multi

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a `Foo` schema in my app that `has_many` of the schema `Bar`.

```
  schema "foos" do
    field :content, :string 
    has_many :bars, MyApp.Content.Bar, foreign_key: :foo_id
  end

  schema "bars" do
    field :content, :string 
    belongs_to :foo, MyApp.Content.Foo, foreign_key: :foo_id
  end
```

I want a function that takes an id for a `Foo`, creates a copy of that `Foo` and inserts it, and then creates copies of all the associated `Bar`s with the new `Foo`.  Given a Foo with many child Bars, this function will copy that Foo and all those Bars in one go.

I use Ecto.Multi for things like this, but I'm not sure how to set it up for a variable number of actions.  So far I have this:

```
resolve fn (%{foo_id: foo_id}, _info) ->
  oldfoo = Repo.get!(Foo, foo_id)

  multi =
    Multi.new
      |> Multi.run(:foo, fn %{} ->
        MyApp.Content.create_foo(%{
          content: oldfoo.content
        }) end)
      |> Multi.run(:bars, fn %{foo: foo} ->

        query =
          from b in Bar,
            where: b.foo_id == ^foo.id,
            select: b.id

        bars = Repo.all(query)  # returns a list of id/ints like [2,3,6,7,11...]

        Enum.map(bars, fn barid ->
          bar = Repo.get(Bar, barid)
          Bar.changeset(%Bar{}, %{
            content: bar.content,
            foo_id: foo.id
          })
            |> Repo.insert()
        end)
      end)

  case Repo.transaction(multi) do
    {:ok, %{foo: foo}} ->
      {:ok, foo}
    {:error, _} ->
      {:error, "Error"}
  end
```

This throws an error:

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: [ok: %MyApp.Content.Foo...
```

Is there a reasonable way to do this within Ecto.Multi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `Enum.reduce_while/3` here. We loop over the list, collecting all the inserted bars. If any insert fails, we return that error, otherwise we return the collected values in a list.

```
Enum.reduce_while(bars, {:ok, []}, fn barid, {:ok, acc} ->
  bar = Repo.get(Bar, barid)
  Bar.changeset(%Bar{}, %{
    content: bar.content,
    foo_id: foo.id
  })
  |> Repo.insert()
  |> case do
    {:ok, bar} -> {:cont, {:ok, [bar | acc]}}
    {:error, error} -> {:halt, {:error, error}}
  end
end)
```